# MongoDB+PHP. Как добавить элемент в массив, который сам элемент массива?

Tags: php, mongodb

Есть документ

```
{
"comand": "supermans",
"sasha": [
     "23",
     "M",
     "napadayushiy",
     [
       "Pas1",
       "Pas2",
       "Pas3"
     ]
   ],
"vova": [
     "25",
     "M",
     "zashitnik",
     [
       "Pas1",
       "Pas2",
       "Pas3"
     ]
   ]
}
```

Мне надо у "sasha" добавить в массив элемент "Pas4"
Как это сделать в php? Следующими php-командами...

```
$oldDoc = $coll->findOne(array('comand' => "supermans"));
$newDoc = array ('$push' => array(  ???  );
$ustCheck = $coll ->  update($oldDoc, $newDoc);
```

P.S. В частности синтаксис интересует, не знаю как с безымянным массивом тут работать под 3им индексом массива "sasha".

Answer (score 1):

В общем сам ответ нашел

```
$newDoc = array ('$push' => array("sasha.3" => "Pas4"));
```